# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.22.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have Spring boot admin project with 1.5.17 version...What is the reason for dependency is not getting imported.

Comment: Good question. But perhaps it is better to first update to a current version

Comment: Having the same problem with the current version `2.3.2.RELEASE` and Maven fails to import the rest of the dependencies. Any help?